# How to export data from hive to hdfs in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Can someone say how to push data from hive to hdfs. I could find how to export data from hdfs to hive but not regarding hive to hdfs.

Any help great thanx..

Comment: Please see relevant section on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to post your relevant codes, issue that you are facing, analysis done to resolve that issue...

Comment: The underlying data seen (and queried) in Hive resides on HDFS. The easiest way would be via API's or selec HQL's to get data out from HIve and store them on HDFS

Answer (score 0):

Check [INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries) in language manual

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY directoryLocation select_statement1
```

Or Hive basically stores data in HDFS. So you can use the hive warehouse location if it's internal table or the corresponding data location if it's a external table.

Alternatively you can also copy hive underlining data to your desired location.

```
hadoop fs -cp /hive/location /desired/location
```

Hope this helps.